# GraniteDS with Parsley framework

Tags: java, apache-flex, graniteds, parsley

I'm looking for an example about using GraniteDS for remote and 
Parsley ( client-side ) for MVC / IOC. 
The problem is that they both use the [inject] metadata...

So, if anyone has a solution for this ? Or a little example...

Thanks !

Comment: Why is it a problem that they both use inject metadata?  Are there specific GraniteDS AS3 classes?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this post : [Experiences with Parsley and GraniteDS](http://www.spicefactory.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=845&start=0&postdays=0&postorder=asc&highlight=)